# reCAPTCHA on multiple subdomains

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

We're looking to install reCAPTCHA v3 on multiple subdomains, such as www.example.com, blog.example.com and app.example.com.

In some instances, such as login, both the form render and processing happen on the same subdomain (app.example.com). However, other times, such as user registration, the form is rendered on one subdomain (www.example.com) and submitted for processing on another subdomain. (app.example.com)

Should we have a seperate "site" for each subdomain, with it's own key? Or should we have a single "site" with a shared key?

Finally, would you list each subdomain explicitly in the "domain" setting of the site(s), or just the parent example.com domain?

Appreciate hearing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Adding example.com should be sufficient.

The tooltip for **Domain** on the reCAPTCHA settings page states that:

> Your registration is restricted to the domains you enter here, plus
> any subdomains. In other words, a registration for example.com also
> registers subdomain.example.com

However from my tests it seems that it **doesn't work for AMP websites**.

Perhaps the bug is also affecting regular websites, I haven't checked that.